# How to get a name from the user and display it in a Toast using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I made a custom dialog that contains an `EditText` to make the user enter his name. When the user clicks "SAVE" I want to display his name in a `Toast`. I made this bellow code, but the application keeps stopping when I click "SAVE". I would like to know where is the error?

```
change_name.setOnClickListener {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_name,null,false)
    builder.setView(inflater)
    builder.setPositiveButton("SAVE") { dialog, id ->
        val name = entered_name.text.toString()
        Toast.makeText(this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    builder.create().show()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omar welcome to the **SO** community.

In your code what you're doing is making a custom dialog and calling the dialog provided positive buttons `onClick` I'm sure your code crashes at this line of code

```
val name = entered_name.text.toString()
```

Because it didn't get the synthetic property of your `EditText` directly.

You need to modify your code a little bit.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
val inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_name,null,false)
builder.setView(inflater)
val yourEditText :EditText = inflater.findViewById(R.id.entered_name)
builder.setPositiveButton("SAVE") { dialog, id ->
    val name = yourEditText.text.toString()
    Toast.makeText(this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

builder.create().show()
```